# Google Maps and Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, geolocation

I built an app back in the day on rails 2.3x using geokit and y4mr-gm.

I am now building an app and Rails 3 and curious if there are any better solutions.

Basically I have a model Business that has an address.  When a user searches for or browses the Businesses I want to have a map at the bottom that displays a marker for each business.

I could do this via geokit and y4mr-gm (though I hear there can be some trouble with Rails 3) but I am hoping for a more elegant solution.  Is there anything recent I could use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been really happy with [Geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder). Its actively maintained and very simple. I ask for a street address and get geocoder to fill in the lat/lng fields before I save my model. It's really painless to implement.

When it comes to displaying the stuff on a map, I am still writing the JS myself, but using jQuery to do it. If you are looking for a working example of the JS with jQuery you can see mine [here](http://capoeiraottawa.ca/javascripts/locations.js).

Comment: do you still have the JS with jQuery your mention, I'm interesting... thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I would say screw the plugins and just use straight up javascript from Google Maps API v3... its really not that much code and G has very accurate geocoder.  Just create a js array of businesses in your view and use the some js to load the map and markers.

UNTESTED code, but it should be pretty close:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
addresses = [];
<% @businessses.each do |biz| %>
  addresses.push('<%=biz.address%>');
<% end %>

function renderYoMap(addresses){
  var gmapOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(38,-97),  //near the middle of the US
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  // initialize the map with your options
  gmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),gmapOptions);

  // probably want to recenter on the first marker, so lets use a flag
  recentered = false;

  //iterate through your addresses
  for (i in addresses) {
    address = addresses[i];
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    //geocode it to get marker position
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
      lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
      position = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
      markerOptions = {
        map: gmap,
        position: position
      };
      //create your marker on the map
      new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);

      //recenter that thang if it hasnt been already
      if (!recentered){
        gmap.setCenter(position);
        recentered = true;
      }
    }
  }
}

renderYoMap(businesses);
</script>
```

Of course you can get alot fancier, but this should give you the basic functionality you are looking for.  The google geocoder limit is 1000 a day, but that is client-side, so that should not be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one you should check out:

https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have several options, [ruby tool box](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/geocoding___maps.html) can help, but it doesn't looks up to date.

I suggest https://github.com/joshuamiller/cartographer

> Cartographer generates painless Google
>   Maps for your Rails application. It
>   supports Google Maps API v3 & comes
>   with all the goodies (MarkerManager &&
>   MarkerClusterer) for managing large
>   number of markers with least effort.

have fun